# Linux permission octal representation

Tags: linux, permissions

I want to know the octal expression of the linux file permission command:

```
-rwxr-xr-t
```

Comment: Most `chmod`s will allow you to use symbolic mode e.g. `chmod u=gwx,go=rX,+t`

Comment: Do you know how to convert binary to octal?

Answer (score 0):

The `stat` command should be able to handle this:

`stat -c "%a %n" /path/to/your/file`

Your specific file permissions are represented by the octal `1755`